# How do {{result}} and $scope.result relate in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I understand binding a model to an element. For example... `<pre ng-model="result">`. 
I understand that this comes from the $scope.result variable.

But how does these relate?

```
{{result}}

$scope.result = data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever angular sees "{{...}}" is says, "Hmm... there must be a $scope variable in here with that name, somewhere". Then it looks into it's piggy bank of scope variables and looks for it. If it finds it, it places that scope variables value into the {{...}} and removes the ...